# Measurable Functions Royden p63 Q15

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e. on $E$ and $m\left(E\right) < \infty$. Show that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is a measurable set $F$ contained in $E$ and a sequence of $\{\phi_n\}$ of simple functions on $E$ such that $\{\phi_n\} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on
on $F$ and $m\left(E ∼ F\right) < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $f$ is finite a.e. and the measure $m$ is continuous from above, we have

$$0 = m(|f|= \infty) = \lim_{R \to \infty} m(|f| \geq R).$$

In particular, we can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large such that $$m(|f| \geq N) \leq \epsilon. \tag{1}$$ Define

$$A_{k,n} := \{x \in E; k 2^{-n} \leq f(x) < (k+1) 2^{-n}\}$$

and set

$$\phi_n(x) := \begin{cases} k 2^{-n}, & \text{if $x \in A_{k,n}$ for some $k \in \{-N 2^n,-N (2^n+1),\ldots, N(2^n-1)\}$}, \\ N, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

(Draw a picture!) Check that $(\phi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of simple functions satisfying

$$|\phi_n(x)-f(x)| \leq 2^{-n} \qquad \text{for all $x \in F := \bigcup_{k=-N 2^n}^{N(2^n-1)} A_{k,n} = \{|f| \leq N\}$}.$$

This implies the uniform convergence on $F$. Finally, since $F \supseteq \{|f| \leq N\}$, it follows from $(1)$ that $m(E \backslash F) \leq \epsilon$.